How to embed Qiskit into proprietary setting
We have our own custom processor and control electronics. We want to be able to use qiskit on our processor. Our hardware returns measurement IQ samples. We can generate samples from qiskit and run the processor. However, we would also like to use qiskit experiments library. For that, we want to create a custom backend that wraps around our hardware. How to create a backend that also makes the result available to qiskit?

what's the question?

How to make our data (IQ samples, one pair per shot)  available on qiskit?

What do you mean with “available on qiskit “?

@DanieleCuomo An example: We want to be able to read results on our hardware using job.result()

Creating a custom backend is a bit complicated task (I might be wrong). But for what you want I would suggest you to take a look at the GenericBackendV2 python code from the qiskit GitHub. In this code on line 70 they define _QUBIT_PROPERTIES which consists of T1 and T2 information. Modify these for your custom backend. Now to include measurement noise, change the measure error in the _NOISE_DEFAULTS defined on line 50, and I think you will also have to change something in acquire_channel function on line 550.
This is the best I could find from my experience with qiskit. Hope this helps!
